# Float32 to Int16 - Javascript (Web Audio API)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to convert Float32 to Int16. But so far, is not effective. Because the output audio will generate lots of clippings (so, very poor audio output). I am using this function:

```
function convertoFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
  var l = buffer.length;  //Buffer
  var buf = new Int16Array(l/3);

  while (l--) {
    if (l==-1) break;

    if (buffer[l]*0xFFFF > 32767)
      buf[l] = 32767;
    elseif (buffer[l]*0xFFFF < -32768)
      buf[l] = -32768;
    else 
      buf[l] = buffer[l]*0xFFFF;
  }
  return buf.buffer;
}
```

If I implement the [gainNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/GainNode) previously, the clipping effect is less perceptible. But is not a desirable way, because the purpose is to be effective in every microphones.  The clipping effect is visible in this Matlab plot:

[image: clipping effect]

Comment: You need to show more of what you're doing.  Also, WebAudio expects the data to be in the range -1 to 1, so I don't understand why you want to convert your float samples to int16's.

Comment: I suppose it might have something to do with the fact that PCMs require Int16s.

Comment: 16-bit PCM (LINEAR16) is often used as input for audio processing pipelines (speech-to-text, voice activity detection, speaker labelling, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing the while by this, is the solution:

```
while (l--) {
    s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, samples[l]));
    buf[l] = s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF;
    //buf[l] = buffer[l]*0xFFFF; //old   //convert to 16 bit
  }
}
```

Now, the records sounds perfect and the Matlab plots to.

Comment: Looks like your original problem was that you were multiplying by `0xFFFF` (65535), not `0x8000` (32768) or `0x7FFF` (32767), so inputs between `[-0.5, 0.5]` were getting doubled, and inputs in `[-1, -0.5)` and `(0.5, 1]` were getting clipped. The simplicity of the new code is irrelevant (nice, but not solving anything), it's the fix to the constants that mattered.

Comment: So, actually, this has nothing to do with WebAudio?

Comment: @RaymondToy all of this values are from WebAudio API.

Comment: Small error. Should be ```buf[l/3]``` instead of ```buf[l]```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
const int16Array = Int16Array.from(buffer, x => x * 32767);
```