# How to convert mic audio input to LINEAR16 encoding BASE64 string using javascript

Tags: api, speech

I am using google cloud speech API to convert speech to text by using mic. I am getting the arraybuffer of audio, now I need to convert it to linear16 encoding base64 string in Javascript. Please suggest if any possible solution for this.

Comment: where does your arraybuffer comes from, it should already have an encoding at this point, what is it?

Comment: Hi Kaiido,
I am using Recorder.js library to record the mic audio.
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

This library provides following functions:

rec.clear()
rec.record()
rec.stop()
rec.getBuffer([callback])

So I am getting array buffer from function getBuffer()

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any solution or alternative for this? If you got please update. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Audio buffer Data Is in Float32 (PCM 32-bit data) bit format you need to convert it into int16 (Linear16).
[conversion directly from the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738873/float32-to-int16-javascript-web-audio-api)

Then You can the convert the data to base64.